# nginx docker, how to change the public path?

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, web

I want to configure nginx with docker.
My website structure is something like:

```
root
..controller/phpFile1.php
..controller/phpFile2.php
..controller/phpFileN.php
..public/index.php
..public/css/file.css
.. and so on
```

I have read various guides that recommend configurations of this type:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  my-app:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/path/to/public:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    environment:
      # NGINX-PROXY ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES: UPDATE ME
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=your-website-one.com 
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=your-website-one.com 
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=your.email@domain.com
      # /END NGINX-PROXY ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
    expose:
      - 80
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

But..
What I should do is link the site folder inside the docker and specify the path to the public folder.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *docker-compose.yml*:

Create a block:

```
nginx:
  container_name: nginx
  image: nginx:latest
  env_file:
    - .env # If any environment variables used, place them in .env
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
  volumes:
    - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d # This maps nginx config volume
    - ./public:/public # This maps your local public directory volume
```

Now, in the same level, create a directory

```
./config/nginx/config.d
```

and place a file *local.conf* on that level so you have

```
./config/nginx/config.d/local.conf
```

The deafult *nginx.conf* provided with the image will read any *.conf* files
unless you overwrite it, which is not needed in your case.

In your `./config/nginx/conf.d/local.conf` add a or edit block *server* that specifies
your desired root location:

```
server {
    root /public; # That location corresponds to one mapped in docker-compose.yml
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|woff|css|js|xml|txt)$ {
        expires 7d;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~ \.(?:swf|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar|doc|docx|docm)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

This is just an example **server** block which you'll have to adjust you your needs, specify the desired **root** location, server name and additional locations.
In this example I'm assuming your `./public` dir is on the same level - if it's on a higher level or lower level in directory tree you'll need to adjust it so it will correspond to the location of *docker-compose.yml* and the configuration provided in the `nginx` configuration block of *docker-compose.yml*.

Comment: Ty so much ! I'll try !